# how to reuse multiple UIView objects generated in a function 

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, uigesturerecognizer

I

I generated multiple UIView objects in an initierScrollView function within a custom scrollView class. I tagged each of that object and inserted each one in a NSMutableArray object. 
Than I associated a UIPanGestureRecognizer with each of that view object.

```
    -(void)initierScrollView
    {
        int i;
        for (i=0; i<6; i++) {

            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];
            UIImageView *bouton = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
            [bouton setTag:i];
            [bouton setFrame:CGRectMake(10+62*i,10,62,55)];
 classementBoutons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:40];
            [classementBoutons insertObject:bouton atIndex:i];
            bouton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

            UIPanGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
            //recognizer.delegate = self; 
            [bouton addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];


            [self addSubview:bouton];
    }
```

Now I'm trying to reuse the objects by choosing the one which is moving through Gesture. I tried the method where I grab each object from my NSMutableArray (as defined under header file) but the Xcode doesnt seem to recognize them (there is no new move).

```
-(IBAction)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"Mouvement ok");
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self];
    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x, 
                                         recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self];


    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        NSLog(@"voila c'est fait");
        [[classementBoutons objectAtIndex:2]setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100)];

    }
}
```

I dont know why the object inserted in a Mutable array can't be recognized after they are grabbed out from it?

Thanks for your responses.

Victor

Comment: What do you see if you replace `(@"voila c'est fait")` with `(@"Array: %@, Button: %@", classementBoutons, [classementBoutons objectAtIndex:2])`?

Comment: it responds null/null. It doesn't recognize the objects in the array although they are seen on the screen.

Comment: More to the point, it doesn't think you have that array initialized.  Where do you allocate the array?

Comment: '@interface TapScrollView : UIScrollView <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> {
    
  //  id<TapScrollViewDelegate> delegate;
    NSMutableArray *classementBoutons;
    int n;
    int o;
//UIImageView *bouton;

}'

Comment: That declares the name of a variable that will point to a `NSMutableArray`; it doesn't actually create/allocate the array.

Comment: I changed my code by adding the allocation, now it wont simply load the views.